# Updating in-app purchase price App Store not working

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect

I have changed the price of one of my in-app purchases from Price Tier 1 (Paid) to Price Tier 0 (Free) - this is to encourage people to download the app when I promote it.

The problem is, however, is that I changed it a few hours ago and the app is still showing the Price Tier 1 price for the in-app purchase.

How do I fix this? - Is an app update needed to cause this price change to happen? - If so how can limited time promotion be done?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698734/unable-to-change-the-price-tier-in-the-in-app-purchase?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443746/updating-price-of-in-app-purchase?rq=1